# wordpress PHP related posts last child

Tags: php, css, wordpress, css-selectors

3 posts are displayed and under each of them there is a thin 1px border line - the last (3rd) post should not have this border. How to do that?

Code:

```
    <?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3 );
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>

                    <!-- TITLE -->
                    <div class="proponowanytitle">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </div>

                    <!-- DATE -->
                    <div class="proponowanydate">
                    <?php the_time('m F Y');?>
                    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

CSS:

```
    .proponowanytitle {
    color:#34a694;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:400;
    padding:15px 0 0 0;
    margin:0;
}

.proponowanydate {
    color:#999a9b;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:400;
    padding:0 0 15px 0;
    margin:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e2e2e3;
}


.proponowanydate:last-child {
    color:#999a9b;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:400;
    padding:0 0 15px 0;
    margin:0;
}
```

It doesn't work, i tried :not(:last-child) as well. Can anyone help me set the last-child?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other comment, you can use the `:last-child` pseudo class. However, you need to make sure the last `.proponowanydate` is the last child of it's parent.

To make sure this happens, add in a wrap/container div:

HTML/PHP

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3 );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>

        <!-- TITLE -->
        <div class="proponowanytitle">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </div>

        <!-- DATE -->
        <div class="proponowanydate">
        <?php the_time('m F Y');?>
        </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.proponowanytitle {
    color:#34a694;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:400;
    padding:15px 0 0 0;
    margin:0;
}

.proponowanydate {
    color:#999a9b;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:400;
    padding:0 0 15px 0;
    margin:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e2e2e3;
}

.proponowanydate:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: Just seen your edit. You may not need the container div (but best to be safe). The :last-child class will override the previous styles. Therefore, simply leaving out border-bottom will not work. You need to _override_ border-bottom by adding it to the :last-child class like I did in my example

Comment: Unfortunetly my low reputation doesn't allow me to do it, but thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS `:last-child` selector after adding a parent element. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp).

```
.proponowanydate:last-child{
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: Your edit makes your answer completely incorrect. `:last-child` is intended to describe the child, not the parent.